# R/sf: Some edges are crossing in a MULTIPOLYGON. How to make it valid when using S2 geometry?

Tags: shapefile, r, sf, multi-polygon

**Goal**: I would like to know the [NUTS region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenclature_of_Territorial_Units_for_Statistics) (2016 version) of points in Europe.

**Method**: (1) Download the [official geodata](https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2016-01m.shp.zip) from Eurostat, (2) Use `st_join` from `sf` with `R`.

**Problem**: I've updated `sf`, now using v1.0. [Now that it uses S2 geometry](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1649), I have an error message:

```
Error in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) : 
  Evaluation error: Found 2 features with invalid spherical geometry.
[821] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 299 crosses edge 301
[1102] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 575 has duplicate vertex with edge 579.
```

Note that it was not generating an error before the update of `sf`.

**Part of a solution**: I've used `st_make_valid`. Now I have a shorter error message:

```
Error in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) : 
  Evaluation error: Found 1 feature with invalid spherical geometry.
[821] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 299 crosses edge 301.
```

**Minimal example**:

```
library(sf)
path_to_shape_file_NUTS = "NUTS_RG_01M_2016_4326_LEVL_3.shp"
shape_file_NUTS_WGS84 = st_make_valid(st_read(path_to_shape_file_NUTS, quiet=TRUE))
y_coord <- c(46.976, 46.948)
x_coord <- c(7.483, 7.45)
coordinates_as_df <- data.frame(x_coord, y_coord)
coordinates_WGS84 <- st_as_sf(x = coordinates_as_df, 
                                  coords = c("x_coord", "y_coord"), 
                                  crs = 4326)
overlay <- st_join(coordinates_WGS84, shape_file_NUTS_WGS84, join=st_intersects)
print(overlay)
```

You should be able to get the shapefile using this [link](https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2016-01m.shp.zip), then opening the zip file "NUTS_RG_01M_2016_4326_LEVL_3.shp.zip" in the zip file.

**My question**: How to get rid of the error message and get the NUTS region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider getting the NUTS regions via [{giscoR}](https://dieghernan.github.io/giscoR/) package - it serves formally valid NUTS regions.

```
nuts <- giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(year = '2016')
all(sf::st_is_valid(nuts))
[1] TRUE
```

The example is now:

```
library(sf)
library(giscoR)
NUTS_WGS84 = gisco_get_nuts(year = '2016')
y_coord <- c(46.976, 46.948)
x_coord <- c(7.483, 7.45)
coordinates_as_df <- data.frame(x_coord, y_coord)
coordinates_WGS84 <- st_as_sf(x = coordinates_as_df, 
                                  coords = c("x_coord", "y_coord"), 
                                  crs = 4326)
overlay <- st_join(coordinates_WGS84, NUTS_WGS84, join=st_intersects)
print(overlay[overlay$LEVL_CODE == 3, ])
```

And the output:

```
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 9 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 7.45 ymin: 46.948 xmax: 7.483 ymax: 46.976
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  NAME_LATN MOUNT_TYPE CNTR_CODE URBN_TYPE COAST_TYPE   FID NUTS_NAME NUTS_ID LEVL_CODE             geometry
4      Bern          3        CH         2          0 CH021      Bern   CH021         3 POINT (7.483 46.976)
8      Bern          3        CH         2          0 CH021      Bern   CH021         3  POINT (7.45 46.948)
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't know that :( It is possible, indeed likely, but levels 1,2,3 could mean many things

Comment: I've checked and I don't think the "URBN_TYPE" corresponds to DEGURBA, since DEGURBA is defined for smaller spatial units. But thanks again for the NUTS, it helps already a lot!

Answer (score 7):

The [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/404388/6432) by [Jindra Lacko](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/101912/jindra-lacko) is specific to NUTS regions. Just a quick fix if you have an invalid geometry after updating `sf` to v1.0:

```
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
```

It does not solve the problem, but it brings back the old way of working.
I still don't have a general solution to make a geometry valid when using S2, but just if it could help someone...

Answer (score 5):

While the specific dataset mentioned in the question works for me with the latest `sf` (1.0-2), I had basically the same issue with other EU datasets, namely those on [local administrative units (LAU)](https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v2/lau/download/) imported via shapefiles for 2019 and 2020 (previous years seem to be fine).

`sf::st_make_valid()` does not help, but projecting them with `sf::st_transform(crs = 3857)` (and then back to `sf::st_transform(crs = 4326)` if needed) fixed this for me.

Comment: Curious what's happening here, why does projecting back and forth fix the issue?