# Fix features with invalid spherical geometry (polygon shape file) for s2 geometry (V 1.0) in sf() within R [st_join() or st_intersection()]

Tags: shapefile, r, intersection, spatial-join, sf

Since the update of the `sf` package (V1.0) simple operations such as `st_join()` or `st_intersection()` may be hampered by `features with invalid spherical geometry` such as:

```
[XY] Loop XY is not valid: Edge XY crosses edge XY
[XY] Loop XY is not valid: Edge XY has duplicate vertex with edge XY.
```

A quick fix and second best solution is to turn off s2 by `sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)`, but ideally would be to **fix the features with invalid spherical geometry**, so that s2 can process it.

**How to do in R?**

Related questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68478179/how-to-resolve-spherical-geometry-failures-when-joining-spatial-data/68481205#68481205) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404385/r-sf-some-edges-are-crossing-in-a-multipolygon-how-to-make-it-valid-when-using/404454), but offer only work-arounds to the `features with invalid spherical geometry` problem.

To reproduce the problem download the following shapefile [here](https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v2/nuts/download/ref-nuts-2016-01m.shp.zip), and run:

```
path_to_shape_file_NUTS = "NUTS_RG_01M_2016_4326_LEVL_3.shp"
shape_file_NUTS_WGS84 = st_make_valid(st_read(path_to_shape_file_NUTS, quiet=TRUE))
y_coord <- c(46.976, 46.948)
x_coord <- c(7.483, 7.45)
coordinates_as_df <- data.frame(x_coord, y_coord)
coordinates_WGS84 <- st_as_sf(x = coordinates_as_df, 
                                  coords = c("x_coord", "y_coord"), 
                                  crs = 4326)
overlay <- st_join(coordinates_WGS84, shape_file_NUTS_WGS84, join=st_intersects)
print(overlay)
```

Comment: You may consider `s2::s2_rebuild()` to repair the s2-invalid geometry. Like in the first SO answer you linked; it may not work always, but it often does...

Comment: You have to *very carefully* consider whether to rebuild with spherical geometry. If your lines are formally defined as straight lines between vertices on a projected coordinate system, then using spherical geometry would be wrong. Switching off s2 is *not* always the second best solution.

Comment: @Jindra Lacko: yes sometimes it does, not in my case so.

Answer (score 2):

I realize it is a workaround, and not a generic solution. But issues with invalid geometries are by nature tricky (All happy geometries are alike; each unhappy geometry is unhappy in its own way, to misquote Anna Karenina) and a truly generic solution may be not feasible.

If 2016 level 3 NUTS from GISCO is the only shapefile you are after you may consider accessing it via `{giscoR}` - it should in theory be the same thing, but accessed via API and known to be valid.

Consider this code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)


# shape_file_NUTS_WGS84 = st_make_valid(st_read(path_to_shape_file_NUTS, quiet=TRUE))

shape_file_NUTS_WGS84 <- giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(year = "2016",
                                                epsg = "4326",
                                                resolution ="01",
                                                nuts_level = "3")

y_coord <- c(46.976, 46.948)
x_coord <- c(7.483, 7.45)

coordinates_as_df <- data.frame(x_coord, y_coord)
coordinates_WGS84 <- st_as_sf(x = coordinates_as_df, 
                              coords = c("x_coord", "y_coord"), 
                              crs = 4326)
overlay <- st_join(coordinates_WGS84, shape_file_NUTS_WGS84, join=st_intersects)

print(overlay)
# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 9 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 7.45 ymin: 46.948 xmax: 7.483 ymax: 46.976
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   LEVL_CODE NUTS_ID URBN_TYPE CNTR_CODE NAME_LATN NUTS_NAME MOUNT_TYPE
# 1         3   CH021         2        CH      Bern      Bern          3
# 2         3   CH021         2        CH      Bern      Bern          3
#   COAST_TYPE   FID             geometry
# 1          0 CH021 POINT (7.483 46.976)
# 2          0 CH021  POINT (7.45 46.948)
```